# datagridview in C# not becoming editable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am assigning data to `DataGridView` using `DataSource` property and set relevant property properly still `DataGridView` is not editable at run time.

Comment: Code and or Markup would be good!

Comment: it is window application

Comment: Have you set the EditMode in the properties pane?    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx